# FitBit subscription API: where is the association made between user and app

Tags: oauth-2.0, fitbit

I reviewed the following documentation: [FitBit Subscription API](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/subscriptions/#configuring-a-subscriber%20but%20am%20confused%20about)

Let's say I go through the fitbit setup and create a subscription for my app.  Next, someone joins my website using the oauth 2.0 login for fitbit and agrees to provide access to activities and heart rate.  When the person uses the fitbit api and their metrics are added to the fitbit system.  How does the system know that my app's subscription api should get this person's metrics?  Are there any extra steps that are needed for this to occur or is it driven by the user approving my app to receive this information?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If a user is subscribed to your app and the user uses the fitbit api to add metrics, fitbit should send the data to its servers. Now you will have access to the user's metrics.

Comment: The subscription api seems like it sends or notifies my app whenever a user creates new data for the fitbit.  Is it going to directly send the data to an endpoint that I specify or will it just notify the endpoint that a change has been made and my system has to go and get the data?

Comment: @user1790300 from the documentation "Subscription notifications are sent in near real-time to an endpoint of your choosing."

Answer (score 1):

In the OAuth 2.0 authorization process, the user logs into Fitbit with their Fitbit user details, so the grant code and/or access token returned to your app will be associated with that Fitbit user account.

As explained under [Making Requests](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/oauth2/#making-requests) in [Fitbit's OAuth 2.0 documentation](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/oauth2/), your app must include the access token with each request it makes to the Fitbit API. The way to look at this is that your app will be making requests to the Fitbit API on behalf of a particular Fitbit user.

To make Fitbit call your service endpoint when there are updates for a particular user, your app must call the Fitbit API as described in [Adding a Subscription](https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/subscriptions/#adding-a-subscription). This request, like any other Fitbit API request, will include an access token, so Fitbit will know which Fitbit user the subscription is for.